# MKAnnotationView issue where my pins show up initially then disappear?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, ios6, mkannotationview

I am attempting to debug an issue with my code where the pins on my MKAnnotationView initially show up on first call for a second, but when the map zooms in on the location, all the annotations except for the user location disappears.  Can someone point me to a flaw in my logic?

Below is the code being used.  AddPlacemark is used to get the locations of all my annotations then the MKAnnotationView should show them all on the map.  Like I said, when the map first appears the annotations all show, but when the map zooms in on the location of the user, all my other annotations disappear.  I believe this issue only started occurring when I updated my Xcode so that I could test on iOS 6 and get the simulator for the iPhone 5.

```
    - (void)AddPlacemark {
        if([allplacemarkarray count]>0) {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:allplacemarkarray];

        [allplacemarkarray removeAllObjects];
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;  
    location1.latitude = appdel.MyCurrentLocation.latitude;  
    location1.longitude = appdel.MyCurrentLocation.longitude;  
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location1;  

    Placemark *addAnnotation = [[[Placemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location1] retain]; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [allplacemarkarray addObject:addAnnotation];
    [addAnnotation release];

    if(alllocationArray) {
        for(int i=0;i<[alllocationArray count];i++) {
            NSDictionary *locationdict=[alllocationArray objectAtIndex:i];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
            location.latitude = [[locationdict objectForKey:@"VLATITUDE"] floatValue];
            location.longitude =[[locationdict objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]floatValue];
            region.span=span;
            region.center=location;

            Placemark *addAnnotation = [[[Placemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location] retain];
            [allplacemarkarray addObject:addAnnotation];
            addAnnotation.titletext = [locationdict objectForKey:@"NAME"];
            addAnnotation.logoText = [locationdict objectForKey:@"LOGO"];
            NSString *add1=[locationdict objectForKey:@"ADDR1"];
            NSString *add2=[locationdict objectForKey:@"ADDR2"];
            NSString *city=[locationdict objectForKey:@"CITY"];
            NSString *state=[locationdict objectForKey:@"STATE"];
            NSString *zip =[locationdict objectForKey:@"ZIP"];
            addAnnotation.subtitletext=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@, %@  %@",add1,add2,city,state,zip];
            [addAnnotation setPlacemarkId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
            [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

            [addAnnotation release];
            }

            [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [mapView regionThatFits:region];
        }
    }

    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(Placemark *) annotation {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];

        annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        [annView setSelected:YES];

        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:annotation.logoText];
        UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pinImage];

        logoView.frame = CGRectMake(-23, -6, 63, 48);

        UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
        myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        [myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myDetailButton setTag:[annotation.placemarkId intValue]];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=myDetailButton;

        if(annotation.coordinate.latitude == appdel.MyCurrentLocation.latitude && annotation.coordinate.longitude == appdel.MyCurrentLocation.longitude) {
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        } else if ([annotation.logo isEqualToString:@""]) {
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        } else {
            [annView addSubview:logoView];
        }

        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

        return annView;
    }
```

Comment: have you implemented   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated    ?

Comment: @yunas - I did not implement that since I implemented the mapView for Annotation.  I didn't think I needed to implement another mapView, let me try that and let you know what happens.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually not due to bad code in the app.  Sorry about that!  It turns out my backend code that feeds information to this logic was bad.